# How to crop matplotlib image by circle?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have plotted some data using matplotlib and wanna crop it by circle from center.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
Z = np.random.rand(10, 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(Z)
```

I have tried the idea of masking image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

np.random.seed(100)
Z = np.random.rand(10, 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(Z)

# Create same size alpha layer with circle
h, w = Z.shape
alpha = Image.new('L', Z.shape, 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
draw.pieslice([0,0,h,w],0,360,fill=255)

# Convert alpha Image to numpy array
npAlpha=np.array(alpha)

# Add alpha layer to RGB
Z = np.dstack((Z, npAlpha))

Image.fromarray(Z)
```

But, I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 2), <f8
```

Is it possible to do it using matplotlib only?

Comment: @SamMason Thanks! I have added the example as answer ;) It's a nice method.

Comment: Looks good, knowing primitives like this are exposed is useful!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the link provided by @SamMason. `patches` works well!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

np.random.seed(100)
Z = np.random.rand(10, 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Make a circle
circ = patches.Circle((5, 5), radius=2, facecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(circ) # Plot the outline

# Plot the clipped image
im = ax.imshow(Z, clip_path=circ, clip_on=True)

plt.title('Clipped Array')
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a alpha channel to a numerical array. Alpha channels are an image thing. For RGBA images.

So you need first to convert your array to a RGBA image (which you are already doing, but implicitly only: that is what happens under the hood when you call `imshow` with a 2d array. So the only change is that we will do it ourself).

What happens under the hood when you call

```
plt.imshow(Z)
```

is

```
plt.imshow(plt.cm.viridis(Z))
```

So in two steps

```
rgba = plt.cm.viridis(Z)
plt.imshow(rgba)
```

And there, you can alter the `rgba` part as you wish

```
rgba = plt.cm.viridis(Z)
rgba[...,3] = npAlpha/255.0 # Because when type of image components is float, range is 0...1. And when uint8, 0...255. Yours is float
plt.imshow(rgba)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Z` array is single-channel, if it is meant to be 3-channel RGB as mentioned in OP comments, ie. its shape is `(i, j, 3)`, then you can do something like the following:

```py
s = 256 # size of the image
Z = np.zeros((s, s, 3), dtype=np.uint8) # 3-channel RGB
Z[..., 0] = 255 # red

# mask circle using coordinates
ij = np.mgrid[:s, :s]
# get pixels within circle radius
mask = (ij[0] - s//2)**2 + (ij[1] - s//2)**2 < (s/2)**2
# create RGBA image initially with alpha=0
Z_alpha = np.concatenate((Z, np.zeros((s, s, 1), dtype=Z.dtype)), axis=-1) # 4-channel RGBA
# set alpha channel
Z_alpha[mask, -1] = 255

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(Z_alpha)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

which produces the following figure:
[image: circle]

You can also convert this to `PIL.Image` as you did in the OP:

```py
Image.fromarray(Z_alpha, 'RGBA')
```